# Object stored in session will not match same class after redeploy of project

Tags: java, session, wildfly, ehcache, shiro

I have two classes `Stream` and `Lake` that extend `WaterBody`. The `Stream` or `Lake` are stored in the session managed by Apache Shiro 1.2.4 to be used later.

```
WaterBody lake = new Lake();
session.setAttribute("water", lake);`
```

And retrieve it by using

```
WaterBody water = (WaterBody) session.getAttribute("water");
```

On a fresh start of the Wildfly 9.0.2 server I can store the store the objects just fine to the session and retrieve them just fine. It does not matter if I am storing a `Lake` or `Stream` to the `water` session attribute. However after a redeploy of the project without restarting the Wildfly server I can store to the session attribute `water` the same class type only as before ie: can't store `Lake` first and redeploy then store `Stream`. I get this error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of [Lfwp.fish.water.HydroUnit; to field fwp.fish.water.WaterBody.hucs of type [Lfwp.fish.water.HydroUnit; in instance of fwp.fish.water.Stream
```

The class `WaterBody` has getters and setters for a private field of type `HydroUnit` and since this is inheritied by both `Stream` and `Lake` the error makes little sense.

If on a fresh start the `water` session attribute is assigned to both the same class before and after the redeploy it will assign the value to the session variable just fine and then on retrieval it will throw this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: fwp.fish.water.Lake cannot be cast to fwp.fish.water.WaterBody
```

Since `Lake` extends `WaterBody` it should not have an issue.

With Shiro we are using the ehcache 2.9 for the session cache.

It seems like the `serialVersionUID` is being ignored by the cache or it's generating a different one itself behind the scenes and it thinks that the classes have changed when they have not between redeployments.

The classes:

```
public class WaterBody implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5481729151007010163L;
    private int id;
    private HydroUnit[] hucs;

    public WaterBody() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public HydroUnit[] getHucs() {
        return hucs;
    }

    public void setHucs(HydroUnit[] hucs) {
        this.hucs = hucs;
    }
}

public class Lake extends WaterBody {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -925557850476426686L;
    private String centroidLatitude;
    private String centroidLongitude;

    public Lake(){
        super();    
    }

    public String getCentroidLatitude() {
        return centroidLatitude;
    }

    public void setCentroidLatitude(String centroidLatitude) {
        this.centroidLatitude = centroidLatitude;
    }

    public String getCentroidLongitude() {
        return centroidLongitude;
    }

    public void setCentroidLongitude(String centroidLongitude) {
        this.centroidLongitude = centroidLongitude;
    }
}

public class Stream extends WaterBody {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2556033593701784053L;
    private String mouthLatitude;
    private String mouthLongitude;

    public Stream(){
         super();       
    }

    public String getMouthLatitude() {
        return mouthLatitude;
    }

    public void setMouthLatitude(String mouthLatitude) {
        this.mouthLatitude = mouthLatitude;
    }

    public String getMouthLongitude() {
        return mouthLongitude;
    }

    public void setMouthLongitude(String mouthLongitude) {
        this.mouthLongitude = mouthLongitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider the possibility that the _Class_ itself is being reloaded and the `Class` object is re-instantiated. This could lead to two _object_ instances being considered incompatible even though they seem to have the same class.  The best way to troubleshoot this is to stop in the code just before the exception and compare the classes of the two instances to see if they're the same `Class` object.

Comment: That's what I have done and it appears that it it is the same `Class` just before the cast. If you do `Object water = session.getAttribute("water");` And inspect the `water` object it appears to have all the same criteria as what it needs to be cast to but if you do an `instanceof` check to `WaterBody` it will fail. I probably need to go through it with a fine tooth comb before the redeploy and after when it is that object to see if there is any difference at all.

Comment: As stated above just comparing the object by eye the water object when pulled from the session appears to be exactly the same as when it was stuck in even after a redeploy. I also checked what `ClassLoader` it was using and in all instances it gives me `ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.fish.war:main" from Service Module Loader` so it appears that there isn't any inconsistency there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching into the issue this is what we had found. When the project is ran the first time `ClassLoader` creates the classes when they are used and then stores the objects into the session. After a hot redeployment of that project while the server is running, when it comes to load a `Class` again the `ClassLoader` creates a new instance of that `Class`. However the session still remembers the `Class` from the last time an object of that `Class` was stored and will sometimes let the new objects get stored in the session appearing as that same object. But upon retrieving the object it is still defined by the old instance of that `Class` and thus when trying to cast it to the current instance of that `Class` it will fail.

Our solution is for projects that have objects stored in the session is to separate the classes that will be stored as objects in the session into a separate `.jar` module included with the project that is being redeployed. That way if there are changes to the `Class` files the server will have to be restarted anyway since there is a change to a module dependency. Now if the project is hot redeployed the classes stay intact since they are not in the `.war` file that is being refreshed.